# Windows Phone navigate to a certain page in app when Toast notification is tapped

Tags: push-notification, windows-phone, toast, mpns

I want to open a certain page in Windows Phone application when the user taps on a received toast notification. I guess there may be an event handler for it and I can navigate the app to this page inside this handler. Actually I am not sure about it. This is just an estimation. There may be definite solutions that you can suggest.

Answer (score 2):

```
string toastMessage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
            "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
               "<wp:Toast>" +
                    "<wp:Text1>" + sampleText+ "</wp:Text1>" +
                    "<wp:Text2>" + sampleText+ "</wp:Text2>" +
                   "<wp:Param>/Page.xaml</wp:Param>" +
                "</wp:Toast> " +
            "</wp:Notification>";
```

Here you can replace /Page.xaml with the name of the page where you want to navigate.

Answer (score 1):

In the notification's event handler just add this with the uri of the page you want to navigate to. Make sure to replace "SomePage.xaml" accordingly.

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SomePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Try looking at the bottom of MSDN's [Toast Properties page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662938%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Toastproperties). Looks like tapping on a notification defaults to launching your app.

One way to go about this would be to have a setting, say ToastSetting, that toggles to "true" with the  `toast.Show();` event. THEN, in the `OnNavigatedTo` event have an if/else statement that looks for your ToastSetting being equal to "true". Like this:

```
//Did toast.Show(); fire?
If (appSettings.ToastSetting)
 {
//reset the toast setting
appSettings.ToastSetting == false;
//navigate to different page
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SomePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
else
{
//do nothing
}
```